# How could I, when using i3, have a terminal always be the bottomost application

Tags: i3-wm, tiling

I would like to do something like what this article outlines here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Terminal_as_a_transparent_wallpaper#Setup_by_desktop_environment

But on i3. I'm not certain exactly how. Any ideas would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is not in line with the concept of a tiling window manager. With respect to the visual aspect: just open a terminal, configured to have a transparant background using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you will be there. The terminal will fill the whole screen.

Opening a second window in the same workspace will reduce the terminal to half the screen, and use the other half for the new application. That is how a tiling window manager is designed to work. If you are looking to have bottommost and topmost applications, stacking window managers, e.g. Openbox, will be your preference.